# robomongo fails on aggregate cursor "cursor.hasNext is not a function"

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to work with aggregate cursors in robomongo, but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cursor.hasNext is not a function (shell):1
```

I am using mongodb 2.6.3, and therefore the aggregate framework should return a cursor.
After almost driving myself insane, I eventually tried this using the native mongodb shell and it works properly there.

Why doesn't this work in robomongo? Is there some sort of backwards compatibility option thats turned on by default? How do I turn this off?

I am using robomongo 0.8.4

Comment: Personally, I did not post my questions about Robomongo on SO because there were so many. I just assumed Robomongo does not support a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, in a typical fashion, I couldn't figure out the answer until I posted a question to stackoverflow.

The answer is that robomongo does not currently support the mongo 2.6 shell as of yet. The relevant issue is here https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/520